# Modifying the "proof" completion (environment based on current word) in TextMate LaTeX bundle

Tags: autocomplete, latex, textmatebundles

Editing with the TextMate LaTeX bundle, I'm trying to change the behaviour of the "Environment based on current word" snippet when applied to the "proof" environment. I would like it to behave as a normal (i.e. not a labeled) environment. 
I edited the bundle configuration file (Bundles --> LaTeX --> Edit Configuration File). I deleted the lines

```
proof = {
        triggers = ( pf, proof );
                    content = "\\label{pf:$1}\n\t$0";
    };
```

(from the labeled_environments section)
and added the lines

```
proof = {
        triggers = ( pf, proof );
    };
```

to the environments section. 
Upon application -- typing pf and command-{ -- I now get two choices, both called "proof", with the first behaving as I wish and the second behaving as it used to (i.e. the labeled version). 
Is there a way to get rid of the second?